# Calculate $\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\binom{i+10}{i}(\frac{1}{2})^i$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm not great with summation and its various techniques, so go easy on me. If someone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

This is the sum in display mode: $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\binom{i+10}{i}\frac{1}{2^i}$$

By using the symmetry rule for binomial coefficients I end up with this:
$$\frac{1}{10!}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i}{2^i}\prod_{k=1}^{10}(k+i)$$ which doesn't seem to help.
I tried working something else on the binomial to get rid of *i* and I got:
$$11\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\binom{i+10}{i-1}$$
but yet again, I'm stuck.
I have a feeling that I have to somehow simplify the sum and then use the recursive method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: A well-known series (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem), e.g.) is:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{11}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{10+k}{k}x^k$$

Its derivative is close to what you want:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{(1-x)^{11}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\binom{10+k}{k}x^{k-1}$$ At the end evaluate at $x=\frac12$ of course.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I don't think I ever used the generalized theorem, so I learned about it now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You may note that
$$
\sum_{i\ge0}i\binom{10+i}i x^i=
x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{10+i}i x^i,
$$
reducing the problem to known series.

> $$=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{-11}i (-x)^i=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac1{(1-x)^{11}}=\left.\frac{11x}{(1-x)^{12}}\right|_{x=\frac12}=22528.$$